# npm ERR! tb.match is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having an issue installing csvtojson. When I run `npm install csvtojson` I'm getting npm error tb.match is not a function. How do I solve this?

Comment: What version of NodeJS and NPM are you using?

Comment: node: v13.8.0
npm: 6.13.6

Comment: Not sure why you are getting this error, but you can try downgrading your node version a little to maybe 13.5.0 and trying running the install again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cant get to use NPM right away, try to use YARN and see if the dependencies will install

Answer (score 2):

Removing the **lock file** AND the **node_modules folder** worked for me. Try to remove them and run again **npm install**.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `package.lock` and run `npm install` is working for me.