# Error when using 'npm' command in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm, npm-install

When I use

```
npm install
```

or

```
npm i react-hammerjs
```

for example, the error I get is:

```
tb.match is not a function
```

What could be causing this and what is the solution to my problem?

Comment: Does the following help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60090230/npm-err-tb-match-is-not-a-function

Comment: its bug in oldversion that is no longer maintained, update npm to fix it. [bug](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1257)

Comment: @qrsngky no it does not

Comment: @bogdanoff updated it, still nothing

Comment: @NoDiggityNoDoubt share your npm version (```npm -v```)

Comment: 7.0.8 npm version

Comment: upstream version is 8.14.0, you clearly haven't updated npm,  run `npm install -g npm` if still version doesn't change probabbly you have to update nodejs version.